# «Mais» explétif?

Tags: grammaire, expressions, régionalismes, évolution-récente

J’entends depuis quelques années un *« mais »* que je qualifierais d’explétif dans la mesure où il n’est pas nécessaire à la construction de la phrase et qu’on peut le retirer sans en modifier le moindrement le sens *(voir aussi dans Wikipédia : [explétif d’insistance](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expl%C3%A9tif#Expl%C3%A9tifs_d%E2%80%99insistance)).* Il incorpore aussi sans doute une partie des propriétés d’un *« mais »* exclamatif.

Il s’agit d’un *« mais »* en plein milieu d’une phrase, précédent le plus souvent un adverbe d’intensité conjugué à une hausse du timbre de la voix.

- C’est ce qui rend cette ville **mais** tellement belle et agréable à visiter !
- Cette compagnie se complait dans la mise en marché de produits **mais** vraiment trop controversés !

J’entends régulièrement ce genre de tournure à la radio, par les invités et animateurs *(le plus souvent des invitées et animatrices, en fait),* et bien que je n’écoute guère la télévision, il m’arrive de l’entendre là aussi à l’occasion.

En société, il me semble que certaines personnes ont pleinement accepté cette manière de s’exprimer et l’utilisent couramment, au point que je ne passe guère plus de quelques jours sans l’entendre ici ou là. Pour un certain type d’argumentation, je suis prêt à accepter ce que je ressens comme une innovation linguistique valide, même si je me rebiffe un peu à la couche d’arrogance sous-jacente que je ressens à son utilisation¹.

À l’écrit, par contre, cette tournure semble très peu usitée. Deux ou trois pages de résultats seulement sur Google pour des recherches telles que :

- ["c'est mais vraiment"](https://www.google.ca/search?newwindow=1&biw=1263&bih=759&ei=Cg5RWvLwAsezmwGRhLLoDA&q=%22c%27est+mais+vraiment%22&oq=%22c%27est+mais+vraiment%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...406515.413710.0.414236.27.17.6.0.0.0.594.3556.0j1j7j1j2j1.12.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..9.14.2529...0j0i131k1j0i22i30k1j0i22i10i30k1j33i21k1.0.bEaEyLh-DT8)
- ["c'est mais tellement"](https://www.google.ca/search?newwindow=1&biw=1263&bih=759&ei=qQ9RWsPcDMzAmwH45ozYDA&q=%22c%27est+mais+tellement%22&oq=%22c%27est+mais+tellement%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i8i10i30k1l2.280368.282706.0.285772.17.10.1.0.0.0.498.1782.2-2j1j2.5.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..15.1.468....0.E2cRg6T7gK0)

Les résultats obtenus sont le plus souvent de petits blogues ou des forums en ligne. Par ailleurs, c’est le grand néant sur [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=c%27est+mais+vraiment%2Cc%27est+mais+tellement&year_start=1800&year_end=2018&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=).

Même absence de résultats chez [Gallica](http://gallica.bnf.fr/services/engine/search/sru?operation=searchRetrieve&version=1.2&query=%28gallica%20adj%20%22c%27est%20mais%20vraiment%22%29&suggest=0), où les quelques rares trouvailles ne correspondent aucunement à ce type de construction ici décrit. Nous avons donc à ce point de l’histoire, à peu de choses près, un phénomène strictement oral.

---

**Mes questions :**

- Quelle est votre expérience personnelle avec ce *mais* explétif ? Le rencontrez-vous parfois ? Est-il présent dans toutes les régions de la Francophonie ? *<sub>Je peux d’ores et déjà attester sa présence au Québec...</sub>*
- D’où provient-il ? Peut-on retracer ses premières attestations ? Est-il récent ?
- « Explétif » est-il bien le qualificatif qui convient pour décrire de phénomène ?

---

*¹ <sub>Mon aversion n’est pas grammaticale. Elle provient davantage du ton péremptoire et fermé aux objections possibles que l’expression me semble vouloir imposer, autant par son accumulation d’adverbes d’intensité que par la hausse de la force et du timbre de la voix qui caractérisent le plus souvent son élocution.</sub>*

Comment: Je l'associe personnellement à un mode d'expression générationnel, dans la lignée du "trop" superlatif ("trop bien !")

Comment: Si on me demandais d'interpréter des phrases comme celles-là, je traduirais ces mais par des like en anglais.

Comment: Cet usage intéressant ressemble un peu à l’usage: [«II.− A.−1.a) α) … {Par anticipation des objections à la conclusion} *Il a beaucoup, mais beaucoup plu. Il fut reçu bien, mais très bien*»](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mais), mais où le locuteur ne prend même pas la peine (le risque?) de mentionner l’adjectif avant sauter directement au «mais + adverbes d’intensité».eg:«C’est ce qui rend cette ville [belle et agréable à visiter,] mais tellement belle et agréable à visiter!» «Cette compagnie se complait dans la mise en marché de produits [trop controversés,] mais vraiment trop controversés!»

Comment: "ton péremptoire et fermé aux objections possibles que l’expression me semble vouloir imposer" Comment une expression peut-elle semble vouloir t'imposer quoi que ce soit?,

Comment: @Lambie Une expression possède sa personnalité. La personnalité de cette tournure, selon MA perception, semble vouloir imposer non seulement la conclusion qu'elle introduit, mais encore la puissance, l’écrasante évidence de cette conclusion. C’est un peu trop vitaminé pour le tiède personnage que je suis.

Comment: @PapaPoule J'avais aussi remarqué cette tournure, d'ailleurs tirée du dictionnaire de l'Académie, ce qui lui confère une certaine valeur *(ou une valeur certaine, c'est selon).* J'approuve votre analyse du saut direct sans mention initiale de l'adjectif, et je vois même comment cette accélération du processus donne une nouvelle vigueur à la tournure: répété deux fois, *«belle et agréable à visiter»* serait inconvenablement lourd, tandis que de cette manière, on peut s'étendre sans lasser l'auditeur et enchaîner les qualificatifs *(dans une certaine mesure, on s'entend...)*

Comment: @PapaPoule Il y a cependant plus que votre analyse. Il y a aussi le ton (un peu chantant et montant dans les aigus) associé à ce *mais* «explétif». J'ai un peu de difficulté à le décrire, mais j'entends bien trouver un exemple bientôt et l'ajouter en lien dans la question. Toujours est-il que cette prosodie me semble inséparable de la tournure sur laquelle je m'interroge, alors qu'elle ne me semble ni nécessaire, ni même souhaitable dans les exemples de l'Académie.

Comment: @QuentinRuyant Avez-vous vous-même été exposé à cette expression? Je suis assez d'accord avec votre lien avec le «trop» superlatif. Ici au Québec, cependant, il semble que les femmes de la vingtaine à la cinquantaine sont les principales utilisatrices de la tournure. Peut-être n'est-ce pas strictement générationnel, simplement un tour qui a séduit un certain public qui se l'est spontanément approprié??

Comment: Very far-fetched (and even in English I’ll be hard pressed to coherently express the following thought, so please excuse my fear of trying to express it in French), but could this be an extension of “mais” in French to include the adverbial notion of “just/only/nothing but” found in English’s “but”? ==«C’est ce qui rend cette ville [rien d’autre que] tellement belle et agréable à visiter! … «Cette compagnie se complait [seulement] dans la mise en marché de produits vraiment trop controversés!»

Comment: @Feelew oui, j'entends même souvent des phrases du type "ah nan mais trop, quoi !" pour marquer l'approbation. On peut discuter du termes générationnel. Dans mon expérience (en France) ces expressions relevaient du "parlé jeune" il y a une dizaine ou une quinzaine d'année (employées par des jeunes adultes ou adolescents mais pas par leurs parents) et ont continué d'être employées par cette génération qui a maintenant un peu vieillit... Peut-être en se diffusant également. Mais évidemment cette expérience n'a pas valeur d'étude sérieuse du sujet. Et peut-être qu'on parle d'usages différents.

Comment: "Ah nan ***mais*** trop, quoi!" = Ah no, that's ***like*** too much!||C’est ce qui rend cette ville ***mais*** tellement belle et agréable à visiter ! || That's what makes this city ***like*** so pretty and nice to visit!  [is nan there meant to be non??, not sure].

Comment: @PapaPoule Ce *mais* est plutôt utilisé pour intensifier la qualification qui suit, un peu comme une ponctuation ou un signal avancé qui indiquerait à l'auditeur que quelque chose d'important, de majeur arrive.

Comment: @Lambie Pas non plus pour chercher ses mots. La personne qui utilise cette tournure sait exactement où elle va. Et aucune coupure abrupte non plus après le *mais*, contrairement à *like*, mais plutôt un flot, certes un peu ralenti, mais pas interrompu.

Comment: @Feelew Pour moi, c'est en gros l'équivalent au niveau discursif de like en anglais. Le mot ***mais*** interrompt le flux de la phrase même si on ne met pas de virgules. C'est comme si quelque chose manquait. En tout cas, ce que je dis moi n'a pas grand chose à voir avec comment cela fonctionne en français. C'est juste une interprétation pour une possible traduction du mot vers l'anglais.

Comment: Ça me semble un usage dérivé très directement du "mais de surenchère" (Bon Usage, 14e ed., §1108 b): *Il était beau, **mais** beau!*, *c'était vraiment, **mais** vraiment magnifique* etc.

Comment: @Circeus Très intéressant. Vous devriez étoffer un tout petit peu et en faire une réponse. Merci de votre recherche et de votre commentaire.

Answer (score 3):

Pour moi c'est quasiment de la ponctuation orale.

Je la rencontre pas mal, en France. Plutôt par les jeunes (quand c'est en milieu de phrase).

Je pense qu'on peut le rattacher au "mais" en début de phrase qui devient une interjection : "*Mais naaan !*" "*Mais put**n...*" "*Mais t'es sérieux ??*"

Voilà ma théorie : je pense qu'il vient des contestations d'enfant, du style :

> - Range ta chambre !
>
> - Mais mamaaaan !

À la base il devait y avoir un argument après "mais" ("*Mais j'ai pas fini !*"), mais il est pas indispensable, le "mais" tout seul suffit à exprimer la contestation. Avec, à l'extrême, le fameux :

> Mais-euh !

À partir de là il est utilisé quasiment comme une interjection (comme les exemples du début), "*Mais put***n, tu la bouges ta caisse ??*", pour la surprise et/ou l'énervement.

Ensuite seulement, il peut être utilisé pour la surprise "positive" :

> Mais c'est trop bon ce truc !
>
> Waaaah mais comment t'es trop jolie avec ça !

À partir de là si on prend l'habitude de l'utiliser tout le temps il peut commencer à se glisser au milieu des phrases, toujours pour marquer l'étonnement, ou l'admiration comme dans ton exemple :

> C’est ce qui rend cette ville mais tellement belle et agréable à visiter !

C'est juste une théorie, mais ça me paraît plutôt plausible et cohérent.

Comment: Merci de votre réponse. Je trouve très intéressante votre remarque sur le fait que ça s'entend par les jeunes en France. Je puis aussi constater par les exemples que vous proposez que votre expérience est vraisemblablement telle. Surprenamment, le tour au Québec est très employé de façon sobre et nuancée par des femmes instruites et posées.

Comment: @Feelew En France aussi. La dernière phrase de Teleporting Goat est plus vraisemblable provenant de la bouche d'adultes « bon chic bon genre » que d'enfants.

Comment: @jlliagre Pas de souci ! Tu es allé voir ce que ça voulait dire ? :)

Comment: ***Thanksgiving*** bien sûr ! ;-) En sms, **tg** ça veut dire **ta gueule** :-)

Comment: @jlliagre La dernière phrase de Teleporting Goat était celle que j'ai soumise dans ma question comme exemple d'utilisation...

Comment: Ah oui, c'est vrai. Ça ne change pas ma remarque qui est que cette phrase est idiomatique aussi en France mais inattendue de la bouche d'un enfant.

Comment: @jlliagre Je m'y attendrais en effet, que vos enfants ne soient pas À CE POINT plus dégourdis que les nôtres :) Je l'avais choisie comme exemple parce que c'était là ce que je suis habitué d'entendre. Je suis content, parce que je suis curieux de ce genre de connaissance, d'apprendre que cette tournure est aussi habituelle en France. Merci!

Answer (score 0):

Peut-être une manière de simplifier une tournure habituelle répétitive et un peu plus lourde tout en maintenant le besoin d'emphase ressenti par la personne qui parle?

Un exemple où la tournure sans élision a été privilégiée, sur [Radio-Canada](https://ici.radio-canada.ca/nouvelle/1789985/covid-19-haut-du-lac-clinique-mobile) en mai 2021 :

> Dans le haut du Lac actuellement, comme partout ailleurs, il faut **vraiment, mais vraiment** suivre les mesures.