# Que veut dire « crisse de voyage » ?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, québec, régionalismes

Dans une conversation entre Québécois j'ai entendu cette phrase en réponse à quelqu'un qui demandait au locuteur des nouvelles de sa sœur  :

> Ah, l'histoire de ma sœur, j'ai eu mon crisse de voyage.<sup>1</sup>

Je comprends au ton que B exprimait le ras-le-bol de l'histoire de sa sœur.

Pour ce qui est de ***[crisse](http://oreilletendue.com/2011/09/26/crissement-riche/)*** il est clair ici qu'ici il ne s'agit pas du Christ et je comprends le mot comme un intensificateur, un peu comme l'équivalent du *putain* de mon sud-ouest natal.

Pour ce qui est de ***voyage*** j'ai trouvé [ceci](http://www.je-parle-quebecois.com/lexique/definition/expression-quebecoise/jai-mon-voyage.html) :

> « J’ai mon voyage » n’est pas quelque chose d’agréable puisqu’on l’utilise lorsqu’on en a assez de quelque chose, qu’on est agacé ou dégoûté. On peut aussi l'utiliser pour marquer un grand étonnement (souvent accompagné de « j'en reviens pas ! »).

Mes interrogations :

- Pourquoi cet emploi des deux mots dans un même syntagme ?  Y a-t-il redondance volontaire pour redoubler sur l'effet ras-le-bol ?
- Le syntagme *crisse de voyage* est-il courant ou le locuteur l'a-t-il fabriqué pour la circonstance ?
- Et finalement comment les deux mots *crisse* et *voyage* s'articulent-ils ? Serait-il raisonnable de traduire en français de chez moi par « putain de ras-le-bol ? »

Et j'ai une question subsidiaire :

- Si mon interprétation de *crisse* est correcte, je voudrais savoir si, à l'instar de *putain*, le mot peut être employé pour exprimer aussi bien un sentiment positif (admiration par exemple) que négatif (le ras le bol, le désagrément).

**Ajout :**

Malgré les explications trouvées en ligne, j'ai encore du mal à cerner l'emploi de *voyage*, d'où ma question sur l'articulation entre les deux mots. *Voyage* serait-il éventuellement à rapprocher de l'anglais *trip* au [sens d'expérience](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trip) et qu'on emploie aussi en français dans le sens de « faire un mauvais trip. ».

---

<sup>1</sup> Suite à la réponse de @yagmoth555, la conversation étant orale il est fort possible que la personne ait dit « j'en ai eu mon crisse », je ne suis pas habituée à l'accent québécois.

Comment: http://www.je-parle-quebecois.com/lexique/definition/crisse.html

Comment: @Lph je l'avais vu et n'ai pas donné le lien car ça en apprend beaucoup moins que le lien que je donne, donc inutile. On peut trouver une bonne dizaine de liens vers crisse, un peu moins vers voyage.

Comment: «Putain de ras-le-bol» me semble étrange. «Ras-le-bol» vient-il parfois avec le possessif? Dit-on ou peut-on dire «J’ai mon ras-le-bol», ou alors quelque variation du style «J’ai atteint mon niveau du ras-le-bol»? Je crois que la question de l’articulation impliquera d’une manière ou d’une autre l’idée que le possessif est utilisé dans la construction québécoise. Pour tracer un parallèle correct avec le français de chez-vous, il conviendrait probablement de l’avoir dans l’expression miroir...

Comment: @Montéedelait « Putain de ras-le-bol » est quelque chose que je pourrais dire quand je suis vraiment excédée.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Les deux expressions *« J’ai mon voyage »* et *« J’en ai mon voyage »* sont très communément utilisées, avec ou sans le sacre introductif.

---

#### J’ai mon (crisse de) voyage !

Utilisé pour signifier la surprise, l’étonnement, la stupéfaction. Les versions avec sacre intensifient l’ampleur de la surprise, ainsi que supposé dans la question (positif, neutre ou négatif, selon la situation). Certaines gens ne sacrent pas ou peu, et beaucoup l’évitent ou l’utilisent parcimonieusement en certaines circonstances sociales. L’intensification se fera souvent en réexprimant la chose différemment, par exemple :

- Eh ben j’ai mon voyage ! Si j’me serais attendu(e) à ça ! C’est à peine creyable !

---

#### J’en ai mon (crisse de) voyage !

Vraisemblablement le cas observé par l’OP. Exprime l’écœurement, l’agacement intense, l’incapacité de garder son calme dans les situations auxquelles l’expression s’applique. De nouveau, le sacre intensifie et tend à exprimer un sentiment confinant à l’exaspération. Et de nouveau aussi, ceux qui ne sacrent pas ou ne veulent pas sacrer dans la circonstance du moment auront tendance à réexprimer différemment :

- J’en ai mon voyage de ses plaintes ! Je suis pus capable de compatir ! Complètement désensibilisé aux incessants petits drames de sa vie !

Une autre [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/39575/13100) propose *« tellement »*, qui me semble une autre excellente proposition et une alternative commune au sacre :

- J’en ai tellement mon voyage de ces rénovations.

Potentiellement de nos jours avec un [*mais* explétif](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/28691/13100) :

- J’en ai mais tellement mon voyage des crissements de métal de ces [pépines](http://www.lessucriers.com/t4064-origine-du-mot-pepine) qui travaillent du matin au soir dans la rue.

Il est parfois possible d’omettre le *« en »*, surtout sur le vif, lorsque l’agacement est évident :

- Là j’ai eu mon voyage ! Laisse-moi tranquille !

La version avec sacre serait en ce cas particulier assez hostile. On peut l’imaginer quand des myriades de maringouins vous empêchent de vous concentrer et que vous vous adressez à eux avant d’en écrapoutir un escadron, mais on ne saurait trop la déconseiller dans ses interactions avec des humains. Sinon, il existe d’autres situations fatigantes dans la vie, par exemple un problème de mathématiques particulièrement retors :

- J’ai eu mon crisse de voyage de ce problème-là pour à soir ! Je vas me coucher !

---

#### Variantes (québécoises et internationales)

Il existe quelques variantes québécoise à l’expression *en avoir son (crisse de) voyage*, dont *« en avoir son (tabarnak de) tas »* ou *« en avoir son soûl »*, ce dernier un peu moins commun.

En plus du *« ras-le-bol »* judicieusement proposé dans la question, on pourrait citer une autre expression très similaire, présente de part et d’autre de l’Atlantique : *« en avoir soupé de qqch »*, qui demanderait par contre un sacre adverbialisé au Québec :

- J’en ai crissement soupé de ses insinuations !

On pourrait peut-être aussi tracer des liens avec des expression comme *« en remettre »* ou *« en rajouter »*, qui indiquent elles aussi à leur manière le même genre de sentiment, à savoir qu’il y en a déjà eu assez et que le surplus n’est plus bienvenu.

En avoir eu son voyage, donc, pourrait figurativement se comprendre comme une indication que l’on serait satisfait de se reposer un peu à la maison. Si le voyage est de plus très déplaisant et que le retour au bercail se laisse désirer, on peut y référer en le qualifiant de *crisse de voyage*.

De la même manière, je suppose que lorsque le tas devient envahissant, on se dit qu’il pourrait au moins cesser de grossir. Si le tas est sur le pas de l’entrée, qu’il est constitué de vidanges, que les chats du voisinage viennent y pisser, et qu’il nous empêche de fermer la porte en hiver, on pourra bien entendu le qualifier de *tabarnak de tas*.

Quant au soûl, on ne l’introduit pas à ma connaissance par un sacre, mais peut-être cela se faisait-il du temps de mes grand-parents, je ne sais pas. Le terme lui-même n’est plus aussi présent aujourd’hui que dans ma jeunesse.

---

#### Sacres positifs ou négatifs

Ainsi que mentionné dans les autres réponses, le sacre québécois peut être positif ou négatif.

- Positif : « Une crisse de belle fille !», avec une version possible sans le sacre : « Un méchant beau gars !»
- Négatif : « Un crisse de temps de marde !», ou sans le sacre : « Tout un temps de marde aujourd’hui !»

Comment: Réponse très imagée. Je suppose que les vidanges sur le tas c'est ce que nous Français appelons ordures ?

Comment: @Laure J’avais suivi le lien de la question ce matin et trouvé, tout au bas, un exemple dans lequel on avait écrit, puis barré, le mot poubelles pour le remplacer par vidanges. En effet, comme vous le supposez, la désignation habituelle des ordures au Québec.

Comment: Et c'est de là que je le connais ! Mais pour les non initiés j'ai pensé qu'il serait utile de le préciser.

Comment: J'avais compris entre temps en reprenant, c'est pour ça que j'ai effacé. Je cherchais d'abord encore un québécisme. Pas la peine de préciser c'est pareil chez nous.

Comment: Waou ça c'est des crisses de réponses.

Comment: @Laure Les Québecois ne laisseront sûrement pas passer la chance de détailler quelques expressions de chez-nous, et une question de Laure, c'est la fête! Faudrait pas la/le laisser tomber...

Answer (score 2):

> Pourquoi cet emploi des deux mots dans un même syntagme ? Y a-t-il
>   redondance volontaire pour redoubler sur l'effet ras-le-bol ?

Le juron [*crisse*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/crisse) (du nom *Christ*) peut être « suivi de *de*, pour exprimer une émotion forte concernant ce qui suit » ([entre autres](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacre_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois#Crisse) ). Généralement les sacres sont employés en interjection pour « souligner l'intensité d'une émotion » (Wikipédia, « [sacres québécois](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacre_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois#Utilisation) »), pour marquer le haut degré. Par ailleurs ça peut faire pencher le registre vers le vulgaire.

> Le syntagme *crisse de voyage* est-il courant ou le locuteur l'a-t-il
>   fabriqué pour la circonstance ?

Presque tous les jurons, incluant *crisse*, peuvent être suivis de *de* pour obtenir généralement un effet d'intensification ; il serait probablement tout aussi naturel à mon avis de retrouver *ostie, tabarnac, calice*, par exemple que *crisse* avec *voyage*, tous faisant partie des sacres les plus courants en français québécois ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois#Sacres)). Il s'agit de variations sur un thème.

> Et finalement comment les deux mots *crisse* et *voyage* s'articulent-ils
>   ? Serait-il raisonnable de traduire en français de chez moi par «
>   putain de ras-le-bol ? »

Le mot *putain* est noté vulgaire (Wiktionnaire) et ça rejoint le juron à ce niveau-là.

> Si mon interprétation de *crisse* est correcte, je voudrais savoir si, à
>   l'instar de *putain*, le mot peut être employé pour exprimer aussi bien
>   un sentiment positif (admiration par exemple) que négatif (le ras le
>   bol, le désagrément).

On veut dire comme dans « putain, (ce) qu'il est beau/moche/énervant » ? On peut avoir le même tour (sans le *ce*) ; ou avoir l'intensificateur comme on a dit (*un crisse de beau char*) voire avec un tour différent et la préposition *en* (*un char qui est beau en crisse*). Par ailleurs un sacre avec un plus grand nombre de syllabes permet de ralentir le rythme, ce qui est souvent associé à la stupéfaction je dirais.

---

*Réflexions sur l'expression avec voyage.*

Le tour est un peu différent pour chacun des deux sens :

> « J'en ai mon voyage (de quelque chose) » : l'agacement, être excédé
>   etc. 
>   « J'ai mon voyage » : l'étonnement.

La particularité du deuxième sens c'est que quand on rapporte ça je crois que logiquement il faudrait dire un truc comme « j'ai dit "j'ai mon voyage" » ; « j'ai eu mon crisse de voyage » ne peut signifier qu'on a été *étonné* dans le passé, on aurait dit « je n'en [revenais](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/revenir) pas » (d'un voyage ?).

J'ai entièrement changé d'idée sur l'interprétation à donner à l'exemple avec la sœur (*Ah, l'histoire de ma sœur, j'ai eu mon crisse de voyage.*). La raison pour laquelle on ne trouve pas le pronom *en* c'est qu'à mon avis on n'a pas été agacé par l'histoire de sa sœur : « l'histoire de ma sœur » sert à préciser ce dont il est question ou à revenir à ce sujet après une interruption (tiers, bruit etc.) : on a été excédé par autre chose qui n'est pas mentionné dans la phrase. Une autre possibilité c'est que ça serve d'introducteur :

> *Ah, l'histoire de ma sœur, j'ai eu mon crisse de voyage... parce qu'elle n'arrêtait pas de niaiser et donc j'ai crissé mon camp.*
>   *Ah, les niaiseries de ma soeur, j'en ai eu mon crisse de voyage et donc j'ai crissé mon camp.*

Je ne peux pas vraiment expliquer pourquoi on n'a pas le pronom *en* dans le premier cas alors que c'est clairement l'agacement dans les deux cas mais on est complètement sorti du cadre de la question et ce ne sont que des impressions.

Comment: Rien ne presse, une bonne réponse prends du temps, des jours pour une bonne réponse ne semble pas étonnant. Nous ne sommes pas dans un concours. J'aimerais en particulier plus de choses sur *voyage*, je vais le dire dans la question, car j'ai eu du mal à le cerner. Pour ce qui est de *putain*, dans le sud-ouest de la France ce n'est pas vulgaire, ça peut être un juron, (l'équivalent du merde parisien), un intensificateur (Oh ! putain qu'elle est belle ta moto  ! ; Putain d'temps il pleut encore), [une ponctuation](https://journals.openedition.org/lengas/385).

Comment: Donc oui, crisse a l'air de fonctionner comme le putain Toulousain (signe de ponctuation en moins peut-être).

Answer (score 2):

Je vais ajouter une autre réponse, mais juste pour ajouter un autre point de vue sur l'expression.

Pour l'expression;

> Ah, l'histoire de ma sœur, j'ai eu mon crisse de voyage.

J'aurais tendance a dire que selon le contexte l'expression a deux sens possibles, il nous faudrait savoir la phrase d'après a mon avis.

Le premier sens est celui que vous avez dit, mais le second est pour dire un grand étonnement. Ce qui renforce mon point de vue ici est l'utilisation de l'expression.

> j'ai eu mon crisse de voyage

J'aurais tendance a dire ceci pour dire que je suis tanné, écœurer d'une situation;

> **j'en ai eu** mon crisse de voyage

Je vais répondre ici a votre subsidiaire tout de suite, car si l'utilisation de l'expression était pour l'étonnement, ceci peut devenir positif.

> Si mon interprétation de crisse est correcte, je voudrais savoir si, à l'instar de putain, le mot peut être employé pour exprimer aussi bien un sentiment positif (admiration par exemple) que négatif (le ras le bol, le désagrément).

L'usage du criss ici peut devenir positif..

donc l'example si dessous;

[Julie a accepté de marier Jules! J’ai mon voyage!](https://www.dufrancaisaufrancais.com/attention-elle-a-son-voyage/)

peut tourner comme cela facilement en Québecois;

Julie a accepté de marier Jules! J’ai mon criss de voyage!

Donc ceci me fait demander le contexte de l'utilisation dans votre situation ou vous l'avez entendu. Car *j'ai eu mon criss de voyage* deviendrait juste pour dire, "j'ai été étonné en tas quand cela est arrivé (l'histoire de sa sœur)".

> Pourquoi cet emploi des deux mots dans un même syntagme ? Y a-t-il redondance volontaire pour redoubler sur l'effet ras-le-bol ?

Oui, je dirais qu'ici le sacre devient synonyme de **vraiment**.

Dans un contexte enfantin et si on pense que l'expression est utilisée pour dire qu'il en a ras-le-bol. (Car oui la plupart chicane leur enfants quand ils sacrent :)) L'enfant aurait tendance a dire ceci en Québecois;

> Ah, l'histoire de ma sœur, j'en suis vraiment tanné. (et/ou écœuré)

> Le syntagme crisse de voyage est-il courant ou le locuteur l'a-t-il fabriqué pour la circonstance ?

C'est courant. Je pense ici, je cherche encore des références, mais a mon avis cette expression est native de l'époque des voyages en mer entre continent, qui étaient longs et qui pouvaient devenir pénibles à faire.

> Et finalement comment les deux mots crisse et voyage s'articulent-ils ? Serait-il raisonnable de traduire en français de chez moi par « putain de ras-le-bol ? »

Je dirais que oui. Sinon ceci aussi "putain de bordel de situation" (si on parle de ras-le-bol d'une situation), ou si l'expression aurait eu plusieurs sacres; "putain de bordel de situation de merde"

Comment: Je n'ai pas entendu la phrase d'après mais le ton et la gestuelle montraient un agacement/ras-le-bol certains.