# Évolution de la prononciation du nom du Christ au sacre québécois « criss(e) »

Tags: prononciation, québec

Le sacre québécois [criss(e)](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/39570/358) vient du nom du Christ. Mais le sacre a perdu le son /t/ que les francophones de France prononcent quand ils disent le nom de la personne [kʁist].<sup>1</sup>

- Les Québécois prononcent-ils le /t/ quand ils disent le nom du Christ ?
- Si oui comment peut-on expliquer le passage de la prononciation de la personne [kʁist] à celui du sacre [kʁis] ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Par contre il me semble qu'en France on ne prononce pas le /t/ dans Jésus-Christ [ʒezykri] (à moins qu'il y ait des différences régionales en France).</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il y a très souvent distinction entre les manières de prononcer les mots sacrés et les jurons dont ils sont tirés. Il est improbable que l’on puisse affirmer que la distinction provienne de l’utilisation d’une prononciation plus soutenue lors de la célébration de la messe catholique, puisque celles-ci se faisaient en [latin jusqu’en 1962](http://www.lefigaro.fr/actualite-france/2011/05/13/01016-20110513ARTFIG00614-les-messes-en-latin-ont-double-en-quatre-ans.php) et que le phénomène du juron inspiré de la lithurgie catholique aurait commencé environ un siècle auparavant. Je cite à cet égard un [document](http://www.cslf.gouv.qc.ca/bibliotheque-virtuelle/publication-html/?tx_iggcpplus_pi4%5Bfile%5D=publications/pubf112/f112a8.html) du Conseil supérieur de la langue française, la source de cette affirmation :

> Si les jurons français se sont maintenus jusqu'à nos jours, une nouvelle tendance se manifeste cependant au début du XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle avec l'avènement des chantiers forestiers : il s'agit d'une spécialisation qui s’inspire directement du vocabulaire liturgique habituellement réservé aux ecclésiastiques : les *baptême, ciboire, hostie, calvaire, tabernacle, christ* et *calice* apparaissent dans les interjections de nos Canadiens qui les désignent comme des sacres.

Si les célébrations se faisaient en latin, il demeure sans doute que la vie quotidienne de l’Église se faisait en français, et que les termes lithurgiques étaient sans doute prononcés de manière soutenue et respectueuse. Le tabernacle devait y être désigné *ta-berre-nac-l(e)*, le Christ *crist*, le calice *ca-li-ss*, etc.

La grande majorité de ces termes utilisés comme juron ont subi une modification de prononciation, lesquelles suivent généralement les variations naturelles du langage populaire, selon ses tendances globales ou ses particularités québécoises :

- *tabernacle* devient *tabarnak*, le E devenant A en suivant le même principe qui transforme au Québec *verte* en *varte*, *fermer* en *farmer* ou *merde* en *marde*<sup>1</sup>, et le L final tombant selon une tendance tout-à-fait générale dans la Francophonie qui ne maintient que la première consonne d’un bloc final de consonnes.
- *sacrement* devient *sacrament* et *Vierge* devient *viarge* selon le même principe de transformation du E en A.
- *calice* devient *câlisse*, introduisant ici une différence notable de prononciation sur le A, mais selon une distinction qui [n’est plus le fait de tous](https://francaisdenosregions.com/2019/04/14/qui-sont-ces-francophones-qui-prononcent-laccent-circonflexe/) dans la Francophonie (le A de *calice* est comme celui de *patte*, celui de *câlisse* comme celui de *pâte*).
- *hostie* se simplifie communément en *stsi*, dont le i final s’étire parfois assez longtemps (en toute relativité, bien sûr).
- *Bon Dieu* devient *bon yeu* (sans liaison : aucun N n’est prononcé). Je ne trouve pas beaucoup d’exemples similaires dans la langue en général, mais il y a au moins le *diable* qui reçoit le même traitement. Une expression commune encore aujourd’hui les mets d’ailleurs côte-à-côte pour exprimer que l’on ne croit pas qu’il existe une explication simple à un phénomène observé qui semble incompréhensible : *« Le **Bon Yeu** l’sait pis l’**yâb** s’en doute »*.
- Et finalement, le Christ devient *crisse*, selon le même principe d’économie des consonnes dans le bloc final.

Je termine en citant un extrait d’un [article](https://www.linguistiquefrancaise.org/articles/cmlf/pdf/2008/01/cmlf08162.pdf), qui synthétise assez bien la distinction qui s’est créée entre le vocabulaire sacré et le profane :

> Le procès de l’euphémisation joue un rôle crucial dans la distinction entre les sacres et les objets de culte dont ils proviennent. C’est par la prononciation que l’objet liturgique *tabernacle* devient *tabarnac* ou, par des procédés dérivationnels, *tabarnouche*, *tabarouette*, etc., *christ* se prononce *crisse*, *calice* devient *câlice* et *hostie* est parfois réduit jusqu’à la sifflante *sti*. Il y a donc une double terminologie – religieuse et profane – distinguée par la prononciation et la morphologie des mots.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Sur une note légère, je mentionne ma grand-mère, qui était moqueuse et riait doucement des gens qui cherchaient à masquer leur parler populaire en corrigeant certains aspects de cette langue, dont ces E transformés en A, surcorrigeant à l’occasion. Elle disait d’eux qu’ils *« cherchaient à bien perler »*.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

L'élimination de la seconde consonne dans un groupe à la fin d'un mot est *extrêmement courante*, autant en Français (énormément de gens ne prononcent pas les -l ou -r dans les finales comme -dre ou -ble, par exemple) que dans les autres langues. De fait, j'entends plus fréquemment /cri/ que /crist/ (la prononciation en /cri/ étant parfaitement normale elle aussi) dans *Jésus-Christ* au Québec.

Si le mot *Christ* en dehors d'un juron, est généralement prononcé avec un /t/, c'est plutôt que ce mot a plus de chance de se retrouver dans un langage de niveau relevé (par exemple à l'église), qui s'accompagne d'une prononciation soutenue.

Comment: Est-ce que cela s'applique également à l'orthographe *crisse* qui semble dérivee d'une prononciation qui favorise le /s/ final ? Sinon comment expliquer cette orthographe ? Et quoi du /ı/ auquel on s'attend avant le /s/ ou le /t/ quand une consonne finale est prononcée ?

Comment: la simplification des /st(r)/ finaux est bien attestée en français européen aussi, même si pas à la même fréquence qu'en Amérique quand le groupe de consonnes est suivi d'une pause. Mais personnellement, j'ai toujours un /s/ simple dans des phrases comme "c'est ju**ste** la mini**stre** de l'environnement qui l'aurait demandé"

Answer (score 0):

1. Les québecois prononcent le *t* en disant seulement « Le Christ », mais prononceront *cri* en disant « Jésus Christ. »
2. Outre les phénomènes purement linguistiques, il y a un élément social crucial à inclure dans l'explication de l'émergence de termes religieux utilisés comme jurons au Québec: **le désir de défier l'autorité de l'Église catholique**.  L'emprise du clergé sur tous les aspect de la vie était si écrasante pour un si grand nombre de québécois (en culminant avec l'ère Duplessis et la *Grande noirceur*, avant de changer radicalement dans les années 60 avec la *Révolution tranquille*) que d'utiliser de façon dérisoire et obscène les mots considérés sacrés était une façon de déclarer son indépendance intellectuelle et morale. Cependant, la peur de répression et le respect des traditions étant bien ancrés, la modification de la prononciation jouait également le rôle de porte de sortie, en quelque sorte, comme si le fait de prononcer *crisse* n'était pas équivalent à dire le nom du Seigneur en vain — pêché répréhensible, moralement bas et digne de punition à l'époque.